# Mapping Azure File Share to App Service linux container causes container to fail

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, grafana

I am deploying grafana (docker container, grafana/grafana) to azure app service on linux. it deploys and runs correctly.
When i try to use path mapping to load an Azure file share to /var/lib/grafana, the container fails to start.
This works if I mount it as a Blob instead of a File share, however blob is no longer an option as it is now made read-only.

The file and contents are all same. Not sure why container fails to load when path mappings point to a file share. Easily reproduciple.
Any pointers?
[image]

error: [image]

[image]

issue seems to be related to github.com/grafana/grafana-docker/issues/118 but so far unable to get it to work.

Comment: What's the error? What are the path mappings settings?

Comment: added error screenshots

Comment: Try /var/lib/grafana/ as the mount path

Comment: that doesnt help. issue seems to be related to https://github.com/grafana/grafana-docker/issues/118 but so  far unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue for the Azure File Share. When you mount it to the Web App, you need to see the caution:

> The directory specified as the mount path in your web app should be
>   empty. Any content stored in this directory will be deleted when an
>   external mount is added. If you are migrating files for an existing
>   app, make a backup of your app and its content before you begin.

The difference between the storage blob and file share when mounts to the Web App according to the test, the former will make the all the files appear in the mount point just like what it does in the local docker server. But the latter will not, there is always something wrong with the permission for the mount point.

In this issue, you can see that all the files appear correctly as they do as normal. But when you use the file share, it does not, the file `grafana.db` exists with 0 B. It means the files are not correct.

For this situation, there are two ways to solve it. **One** is that use the Blob storage as it works fine for you. **Another** is that copy the correct file `grafana.db` when it works well to the File share which you mount to the Web App. It will also make it work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

These are the latest logs, you can see the core of the problem in the previous logs.

In my case, I've uploaded an empty sqlite db to the file share first and mount that to the web app and it worked.

Steps:

1. Create empty DB from command line (sqlite3 grafana.db  "VACUUM;")
2. Upload db to file share
3. Mount web app to File Share (MountPath = "/var/lib/grafana/")
4. Set app service -> app settings
   (GF_DATABASE_URL = sqlite3:///var/lib/grafana/grafana.db?cache=private&mode=rwc&_journal_mode=WAL)

Note: If you are using more than one instance of your app or Staging slot, sharing sqlite in Azure File Share will not work. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/47130